# Flex. Client-side image processing

Tags: flash, apache-flex, image-processing, png, client-side

I'm creating some image uploader in Flex with client-side image processing. Processing consists of two steps:
1. <strike>Resizing (solved)</strike>
2. <strike>Converting resized image (represented by ByteArray in PNG32 with alpha-channel) to gray-scale PNG with bit-depth = 2 and no color-palette.</strike>
Is there any existing library that is capable of second step? Something like libpng for C++, maybe?
**Edit:**
It seem I stumbled upon rarely encountered problem. However my descision was to create an AS3 class that is capable of converting bitmapData to 2bit grayscale PNG. I used standart PNGEncoder and PNG format specification (which is not so good as I expected) as basis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) libpng itself.

There's a tool called [Alchemy](http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/alchemy/), which can compile C/C++ sources into swc libraries. Libpng is already ported (it's in sdk examples).

2) [mx.graphics.codec.PNGEncoder](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/graphics/codec/PNGEncoder.html)

The only disadvantage of this standart class is its speed. It's really slow.

Comment: 2) -> I thought that mx.graphics.codec.PNGEncoder converts a ByteArray object containing raw pixels in 32-bit ARGB format to a new PNG-encoded ByteArray object, but still 32-bit ARGB. Is it so?